# Generic Object Param as Its Literal

Tags: typescript, generics, casting, constants, narrowing

I have a simple function that accepts a generic object. The return type should be the same as that object, but narrowed similar to how `as const` assertions work.

for instance. The following should have a return type of `{ a: "first"; b: "second" }` and not `{ a: string; b: string }`:

```
myFn({ a: "first", b: "second" });
```

Is there a mechanism by which we can instruct the type-checker that the return type of `myFn` is its 1st argument type, narrowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The return type should be the same as that object, but narrowed similar to how as const assertions work.

You can achieve this by passing in the type as a type parameter to the function.

```
function myFn<T>(args): T {
  // do stuff
  return null;
}

const a = myFn<{ a: "first"; b: "second" }>(args);
```

[image]

```
type MyObj = { a: "first", b: "second" }
const a = myFn<MyObj>(args);
```

Unfortunately the object needs to be fully defined at compile time as types are not available at runtime.

**Old answer (misinterpreted)**

If you want the return type to be the same as the argument type. Then you can use the generic type parameter.

```
function MyFunction<T>(argument1: T, anotherArg: number): T {
  // do stuff
}

// result will be of type User
const result = MyFunction<User>(user, 9);
```

In some cases, you can just do.

```
// user must be defined as type User above somewhere
const result = MyFunction(user, 9);
```

Comment: `declare function accept<R extends Record<string, unknown>>(record: R): R;`

Comment: `const accepted = accept({ a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" });`

Comment: the type of `accepted` is `{ a: string; b: string; c: string }`, not `{ a: "a"; b: "b"; c: "c" }`

Comment: Bad answers (if they are considered so by people with voting privileges) actually **increase** the visibility of upvoted answers by contrast. So there is no need to worry. In this case however, I would consider the presence of only one, not-downvoted answer which you find unsatisfactory to be an indicator of the need of clarity of the question. It is like an explicit absence of other feedback, https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: The solution here works if you specify the narrowed types on both ends (`let x: {a: "a", b: "b", "c"} = accept({a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'});`. Object member fields do not always stay narrowed due to a limitation in the TypeScript compiler (see issue [31755](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31755)).